# getKieClasspathContainer() method returning null values

Tags: drools, rule-engine

```
KieContainer kieContainer = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
```

The method in the previous line returns a container, but the object "kieContainer" has null values. It does not have a "containerId" and the fields in kProject (which is a field in kieContainer) have 0 as values. There is a META-INF directory in resources, which contains a kmodule.xml. The contents of kmodule.xml are:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
  <kbase packages="com.ruleEngine.drools.section03.step1">
    <ksession name="StatelessPassportValidationStep1" type="stateless"/>
  </kbase>    
</kmodule>
```

What is the correct way to call the `getClasspathContainer()` method?

[Debugger for working project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvQ0y.png)

[Debugger for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szJkS.png)

Comment: To confirm, when you say there is `META-INF` directory in `resources`, it is in `src/main/resources`, yes? Eg. `src/main/resources/META-INF/`?

Comment: Also why are you trying to get the KieProject? If the kmodule is read from your classpath, you should be able to use the container directly, eg. `kieContainer.newStatelessSession("StatelessPassportValidationStep1")`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes, there is. the code i wrote was actually the same of a working sample project. I did everystep truly from the beginning, yet it's not working. kProject is not important tho, i mentioned about it because the working sample project is also bringing the values in it. But my own code does not return. Post is edited. Hope images will help

Comment: Looks like your kmodule.xml is not actually on your classpath. Please check how your project is set up, there might be some configuration in your IDE that you missed (eg. maybe missed or need to redo importing as a maven project or something.)

Comment: It's already a maven project and dependecies plugins etc all set. Actually i did check the version of dependecies many time. Yet haven't manage to solve it. I should consider IDE settings i guess.

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with dependencies, it has to do with the kmodule.xml not being read off the classpath as expected, which indicates that somewhere there is a misconfiguration such that src/main/resources/META-INF is not recognized as being on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the solution. 
If you try to generate a project in IDEA with addition of JBoss Drools library, it downloads Drools_6_2_0.xml into .idea/libraries (it's not maven repo source). And again if you try to get classpath container in anywhere, the versions become mismatched (the version you declared in pom.xml and drools 6.2.0) and it brings null values in "kieContainer" object. 
Just remove the Drools_6_2_0.xml file and problem will be solved. Thanks to Roddy for ideas.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!